# 5v pin not outputting any voltage in Arduino Nano ble 33

Tags: arduino-nano, arduino-nano-ble

I bought an Arduino Nano ble 33 but when I try to power my MQ-4 and MQ-8 sensors, these don't turn on at all, they do turn on if I switch to the 3.3V tho.

Is there anything special that I need to do to be able to use the 5V pin, or my board is faulty?

[image]

P.S: When I say 5V I mean the pin next to the green rectangle.

Comment: Did you set it up to use it? https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360014779679-Why-doesn-t-the-5V-pin-work-in-the-Arduino-Nano-33-BLE-boards-

Comment: I haven't made a solder bridge on the two pads, however I am powering the board through the USB port (please note that this is not the BLE Sense board)

Comment: Oh I have just seen that as an OR when it is actually and AND, so both conditions need to be met

Comment: Says there it needs to be bridged. Also stated on https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/NANO33BLE.

Comment: To be honest, I couldn't find any information on my google search, but you are right, it says so.

Comment: I am new to this, and I am not sure how to bridge that as I don't have any soldering thingy

Comment: FWIW I searched for "Arduino Nano ble 33 5v pin" and it was the top two hits.

Comment: You are completely right I don't know what I was thinking of, the answer was on my first two results too, I think I read OR rather than AND and wrongly assumed my board was faulty, or something like that, sorry about that 

Comment: No worries--it's only obvious after it's obvious ;)

Answer (score 1):

i think you solder the two pads but i'll tell you something: use the 3.3v pin